# The zlib implementation of inflate algorithm

Tags: algorithm, deflate

In the [inftrees.c](http://www.synthesis.ch/indefero/index.php/p/libsynthesis/source/tree/master/src/zlib/inftrees.c), which is the code to construct the lookup table from a canonical huffman representation, the author write:

```
 /* replicate for those indices with low len bits equal to huff */
    incr = 1U << (len - drop);
    fill = 1U << curr;
    min = fill;                 /* save offset to next table */
    do {
        fill -= incr;
        next[(huff >> drop) + fill] = here;
    } while (fill != 0);

    /* backwards increment the len-bit code huff */
    incr = 1U << (len - 1);
    while (huff & incr)
        incr >>= 1;
    if (incr != 0) {
        huff &= incr - 1;
        huff += incr;
    }
    else
        huff = 0
```

I could figure out what's the meaning of drop although I read the comment many times. Another question is what method does the author use to build the huffman code? What's **backwards** increment?

Could you explain it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Backward increment `huff`" means `huff = rev(rev(huff) + 1)`, where `rev` reverses bits `0, ..., len - 1`.

Suppose `len == 7` and `huff` is `1110100` in binary. We look for the first clear bit, clear everything lower (meaning)/higher (bit pattern), and set that bit.

```
1110100
^
1000000 == incr: loop continues
 ^
0100000 == incr: loop continues
  ^
0010000 == incr: loop continues
   ^
0001000 == incr: loop breaks

1110100: huff
0000111: incr - 1
0000100: huff &= (incr - 1)
0001100: huff += incr
```